# Capturing a video from multiple thread Opencv in Cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I am learner in Cpp and opencv,I am trying to access the same video from multiple thread and while doing it I am getting deadlock which is pretty expected

I am creating n threads and trying to process the video by dividing it in n part and simultaneously process it in different threads.this is my void function.I found some python solution of doing but didn't able to understand that.

```
void *finddensity(void *videoinfo)
{
    VideoCapture cap(video.mp4);

    //do some processing on each frame
}
```

and then I am creating thread using pthread_create
is there any ways to access the video avoid any deadlock and also there is struct for videoinfo ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the task was just a course assignment what I did is loaded the whole video frames in memory(which is not a good practice) and than used mutex lock to access the frames from every thread the video size was small (174MB) but I was able to store video at 5FPS in my memory and then completed the task.
But if there is any other general or better solution(which should be there) please respond here thanks BiOS for formatting code :-).